# Why can envoy sidecar control my traffic?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

I run `istio` on `Kubernetes`. I want to know how the envoy sidecar works. For example, after sidecar is injected into the pod, the original container cannot access the outer network without `EgressRule`. How does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the traffic inside the pod is captured by [iptables commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) and directed to the sidecar proxy. Then the sidecar proxy performs routing, according to routing tables it receives from Istio Pilot (a part of the [Istio Control Plane](https://blog.envoyproxy.io/service-mesh-data-plane-vs-control-plane-2774e720f7fc)). The routing tables are based on the Kubernetes services and on the Istio [RouteRules](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.routing.v1alpha1.html#RouteRule). Since Istio cannot know anything about the external services, it cannot route the traffic to the external services without an [EgressRule](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.routing.v1alpha1.html#EgressRule) defined. `EgressRules` define the routing tables for the external services.